# How to include Python-Xlib as a dependency in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, xlib

In my `setup.py` file, I can declare that [`PyUserInput`](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput/) is a requirement for my project (Python 3), but a prerequisite for `PyUserInput` on Linux is the Python module `Xlib`.

This is the relevant part of my `setup.py` file:

```
setup(...
      install_requires=['requests', 'nose', 'PyUserInput'],
      ...
      )
```

I tried putting `Python-Xlib` and `Xlib` into the `install_requires` argument, which didn't work since `setuptools` couldn't resolve those names automatically.

What do I need to do?  I would prefer to be able to have the single command `sudo python3 setup.py install` handle installing all of the prerequisites for my package and not have to ask the user to manually install some prerequisites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pip search xlib`, I found that there was a package named `python3-xlib`.  Adding `python3-xlib` as a requirement in `setup.py` was sufficient.